# How do I set set IIS, MS SQL server to display my PHP errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, iis

Currently, I am migrating my website from a local machine to Windows Server and a MySQL database to MSSQL. However, in order to do resolve the issues with the migration I would need to edit most of the PHP code and the server does no display my error correctly. It just categorizes them under the:

```
`500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.`
```

What do I have to do in order to get proper error logs?

Like: `Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\whereveron on line 12`

Comment: Please add some code so it is better understood what code creates the error and where it is printed.
Also, what web-server are you running your code on now?

Comment: I am running everything on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 64 bit OS. PHP and MSSQL server manager installed and working correctly.

Comment: My only problems are with the migration from mysql to mssql. I would need to put hundred of lines of code for you to see what I have done and what probably could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to display all php errors and warnings is to add these lines at the top of your PHP code file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

For iis server below solution mighe help you

https://serverfault.com/a/19566

Comment: Bless you for your answer! You really helped me figure things out!